# How to configure WSO2IS with secondary user store so user does not have to enter the domain name when signing in?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2IS install in development configured with the OOTB PRIMARY user store and a secondary Active Directory user store. When signing in to WSO2IS Mgt Console I can sign in as an Active Directory user, but only if I provide the domain name like DEVUSERS/devadmin.

I have been experimenting with lots of different settings and I'm pretty sure I had it working at one point so I could sign in with either a PRIMARY user store user (admin) or a DEVUSERS Active Directory user without providing the domain name, but can't reproduce it now.

I should add that I really don't care if DEVUSERS can sign in to mgt console. I just need to authenticate them when they sign in to my web application that uses OIDC to have WSO2IS handle the authentication. I have a Service Provider configured for my web application connection.

I have tried replacing the OOTB PRIMARY user store with my DEVUSERS user store. With that setup users can sign in to my application without providing domain name, so that part works fine. But, the DEVUSERS user I am using to connect the user store (i.e. ConnectionName) doesn't have the 'admin' permission, so can't perform some mgt console functions.

Comment: I decided to implement a custom authenticator and have it add the domain name to username before the call to userstoremanager.authenticate(). That's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in to the IS with any user in primary or secondary user store either specifying a domain name or without a domain name.

Once you try to log in to the system by specifying the domain, IS will look at the specified domain user store to authenticate the user. Otherwise, it will go through all the define user stores starting from primary user store.

In your case, the devadmin user may be exisiting in the primary user store with another password.